# How to find all elements of array in database

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I had taken this array

```
arr = ["1","2"]
```

And I want to find this id's are present in mongodb in user collection or not,
So how do I write query in mongoose for that?

```
user.find({'empid':'arr'},(err,res))
```

I am doing like this.

Comment: I would say first learn to create a query for one then learn how to iterate through an array. Combine those and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should first loop through your array then run mongodb query to find item.
code should be some thing like this:

```
for(item in arr){
    user.find({'empid':item},(err,res))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the query operator [`"$in"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Here's how you can do it.

```js
db.user.find({
  "empid": {"$in": ["1", "2"] }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dkgcXaPNXaO).